# Can I apply for a UK visit visa from a country other than my own?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications, pakistani-citizens, uae

I am a Pakistani currently visiting the United Arab Emirates. Can I apply for a visit visa to the UK from here?
Edit: I am in the UAE on a visit visa.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You do not need to be resident in the UAE.
Immigration Rules Part1 (28): An applicant for an entry clearance must be outside the United Kingdom and Islands at the time of the application. An application for an entry clearance as a visitor or as a short-term student must be made to any post designated by the Secretary of State to accept such applications.

https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-1-leave-to-enter-or-stay-in-the-uk